# Request Mapping pattern at the end of the url */

Tags: spring, url, spring-mvc, pattern-matching

I am trying to map a url with a Spring Controller.
I want the variable petitionId at the end of my url, for instance, I want to map:

```
.../product/all/petitionId/{petitionId}
```

as well as

```
.../product/productId/{productId}/clientId/{clientId}/petitionId/{petitionId}
```

To do so, I have tried to have a RequestMapping in the controller header, like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "product/*/petitionId/{petitionId}")
public class ProductController
```

and in the declaration of the method I want to map

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*/all/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getProducts(@PathVariable Long petitionId)
```

I have also tried with and without slashes with one, two and no asterisks... with same 404 Error result.
The request I want to make is

```
http://192.168.1.27:9999/middleware/product/all/petitionId/20
```

I know I may have the full URL mapping in each method, yet that's not the most elegant way to do it.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation `@RequestMapping` by function.
You can use it in the class but only to write less in each function's requestMapping. Put in the class just what you have in common in all the functions of your controller.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/products")
public class ProductController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getProducts() { ... }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getProductsById(@PathVariable Long productId) { ... }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}/clients/{clientId}/petitions/{petitionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getPetition(@PathVariable Long productId, @PathVariable Long clientId, @PathVariable Long petitionId) { ... }
}
```

You'll end up with the following mappings:

```
/products
/products/{productId}
/products/{productId}/clients/{clientId}/petitions/{petitionId}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your URLs look somewhat complicated.

Have you considered other URL schemes, e.g. for all products by petition:

```
GET http://192.168.1.27:9999/middleware/petitions/20/products
```

or product by id, client id and petition id:

```
GET http://192.168.1.27:9999/middleware/products?clientId=10&productId=10&petitionId=20
```

?